# how to deal with a c++ related warning in boost option header file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost

i have Microsoft Visual Studio (MSVS) 2012 Pro and i have set warning level to a slightly elevated level of 4. when doing this i am getting warnings for some of the included header files from the boost library. the message is this:

```
C:\Users\****\boost/optional/optional.hpp(595): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'T_DOUBLE' to 'float', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\****\boost/optional/optional.hpp(430) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::construct<double>(Expr &&,const void *)' being compiled
      with
      [
          T=T_FLOAT,
          Expr=T_DOUBLE
      ]
      C:\Users\****\boost/optional/optional.hpp(430) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::construct<double>(Expr &&,const void *)' being compiled
      with
      [
          T=T_FLOAT,
          Expr=T_DOUBLE
      ]
```

the code in the file leading to this warning is this (line 610 on most recent beta of boost 1.64.0.B2 still resembles it exactly - but i am not on the beta now):

```
#ifndef BOOST_OPTIONAL_DETAIL_NO_RVALUE_REFERENCES
// Constructs using any expression implicitly convertible to the single argument
// of a one-argument T constructor.
// Converting constructions of optional<T> from optional<U> uses this function with
// 'Expr' being of type 'U' and relying on a converting constructor of T from U.
template<class Expr>
void construct ( Expr&& expr, void const* )
{
  new (m_storage.address()) value_type(boost::forward<Expr>(expr)) ;
  m_initialized = true ;
}
```

what is the reason (=learn to understand) for this warning and how to eliminate it in the boost header for me any anyone else? alternatively thinking: does it make sense to "fix" it in such a global way, or is there a deeper meaning pointing rather to somewhere else (either boost or application codes) to improve or fix those other codes?

Comment: Can you show the part of your own code that caused these warnings ? ie. the code that ended up calling the `construct` function. Ideally as a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You'll get more precise answers then.

Comment: The dangling item in my codes was (example):

`fValue = row.get<double>("Keyword");`

I changed it to:

`fValue = row.get<float>("Keyword");`

As you can see true origin and reported location for the warning are quite far away from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably passing a `double` literal into method that expects `float`. Something like `foo(1.0)` instead of `foo(1.0f)`